# Error: Run sfcgal.sql in cmmand line

Tags: model, 3d, postgis, cgal

i would like to run sfcgal.sql in the command line as I have seen on the different forums in order to set sfcgal working on postgresql. I have Postgresql 9.2, Postgis 2.1, cmake 3.3.1 and cgal 4.6.2 installed in my PC and i would like to know what else i might have missed. I got an error which is attached below.

[image]

I have tried my db password and it doesn't work. I've also tried my PC password, still doesn't work. Now, I wanted to know if:

1. If I have missed something (any software) to install in my unit for sfcgal.sql to run.
2. If is there a default password for sfcgal.sql to run
3. is there any other method to do for sfcgal to work on postgresql.

I really would like to use sfcgal. the main goal I have is to install postgis 3d viewer. I have 3dcity db installed and i have imported 3d models into it. now I would like to use sfcgal.sql to work postgis 3d viewer and view my models.

any suggestions is very welcome!

Comment: Did you compile and install the sfcgal libraries? Only execute the sfcgal.sql script is not enough.

Comment: How would will i compile it . ?.. i'm using windows 7. .

Comment: Sorry, I never compiled it on windows. See the official documentation: [http://oslandia.github.io/SFCGAL/installation.html](http://oslandia.github.io/SFCGAL/installation.html). You must: 1) compile and install sfcgal libraries. 2) Compile and install postgis with sfcgal support.